# Grafana cannot find database from influxDB Cloud using InfluxQL

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I am trying to setup an InfluxDB Cloud data source in Grafana (v 10.2.2) but am unable to locate my databases or buckets.

I am following [this](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/tools/grafana/?t=InfluxQL) example of how to setup the connection but Grafana is giving an error

"database not found: testBucket error reading influxDB"

Here is my grafana configuration:

[image]

The bucket definitly exists
[image]

What am i doing wrong here? When I set this datasource as Flux datasource and give it the appropriate api token, it works fine.

Comment: You specified the "Database" as testBucket but did not provide a user or password.  I found that the user is 'admin' and the password is a token that you set up with the influxdb web ui.

Comment: @RedCricket I left them blank becuase the example in the influx docs had it blank. However putting int "admin" and the token value does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

[As documented](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2/tools/grafana/?t=InfluxQL): If you want to use the InfluxDB2 instance with InfluxQL, you need to [create a DBRP-mapping to your bucket](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2/tools/grafana/?t=InfluxQL#view-and-create-influxdb-dbrp-mappings):

1. [Create a DBRP Mapping for your bucket](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2/reference/cli/influx/v1/dbrp/create/):

   ```bash
   influx v1 dbrp create \
   --db example-db \
   --rp example-rp \
   --bucket-id $YOUR_BUCKET_ID \
   --default
   ```
2. [Create a V1 Authentication](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2/reference/cli/influx/v1/auth/create/) for said bucket

   ```bash
   influx v1 auth create \
   --read-bucket $YOUR_BUCKET_ID \
   --write-bucket $YOUR_BUCKET_ID \
   --username joecool
   ```
3. Use `example-db`, `joecool` and the password you were prompted for in the second step to connect Grafana to your InfluxDB2 instance which will (more or less) behave like an InfluxDB1 instance.

Comment: When i execute the second command, I get an error "Error: failed to verify username "joecool" has no auth: unable to decode response content type "text/html" when using a valid username in place of "joecool".

Comment: @Michael You may need to look up how to do it with influxdb cloud. You are completely out of luck, as it seems: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/reference/cli/influx/v1/auth/ Wild guess: you need to use your cloud credentials.